# Where in the C++ Standard the lookup for an unqualified *mem-initializer-id* is defined?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This is the very first sentence in §12.6.2/2 (C++14):

> In a *mem-initializer-id* an initial unqualified identifier is looked
>   up in the scope of the constructor’s class and, if not found in that
>   scope, it is looked up in the scope containing the constructor’s
>   definition.

I would like to know where, in **§3.4.1 Unqualified Name Lookup**, is the lookup mentioned above ("in the scope of the constructor's class") defined? If it's not there, where can I find this definition in the spec?

My first guess was §3.4.1/7 but I don't think that is correct, because a non-static data member of the constructor's class, which is initialized in a *mem-initializer-id*, doesn't seem to fit the conditions imposed in the 4 bullet points in this paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is 3.4.1/8.  What you have probably missed is that the *mem-initializer-list* is part of the function body for the constructor.  See the grammar production for *function-body*:

> *function-body*:
>
> - *ctor-initializer*<sub>opt</sub>  *compound-statement*
> - *function-try-block*
> - `=  default  ;`
> - `=  delete  ;`

It then follows from 3.3.7/1 that this is in the potential scope of all class members, including those whose point of definition comes after the constructor definition.

> The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only of the declarative region following the name’s point of declaration, but also of all function bodies, default arguments, *exception-specifications*, and *brace-or-equal-initializers* of non-static data members in that class (including such things in nested classes).

Comment: I must tell you that I've wasted a few hours of my time today trying to find this. Many thanks. (+1)

Comment: This can't be right. This interpretation would mean that name lookup would find `struct X { int a; X(int a) : a(a) { } };` is an invalid attempt to re-initialise the parameter: 3.4.1p8 starts with "before its use in the block in which it is used or in an enclosing block (6.3)", which finds the parameter `a`, not the field `a`.

Comment: @BenVoigt 3.4.1 starts as "In all the cases listed in 3.4.1, the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the respective categories; name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name.", so if you say 3.4.1p8 applies to both `a`s in `a(a)`, and a parameter `a` is available, then I don't see how you can interpret it such that the first `a` is resolved differently than the second `a`. I think that entire paragraph doesn't and isn't meant to apply to the first `a` (like I had posted in my answer).

Comment: @BenVoigt 3.4.1p8 specifies the scopes that are searched, doesn't it? Saying it applies, but is overridden by 12.6.2, is basically saying it doesn't apply, as far as I can tell. What part of 3.4.1p8 do you think applies that *isn't* overridden by 12.6.2?

Comment: @hvd §3.4.1/8 first bullet point says: "before its use in the block in which it is used or in an enclosing block (6.3), or". I believe the words `block` here mean the block(s) delimited by {} in the member-function body containing the alluded name. As the name `a` is not in any of these function blocks, the second bullet point is considered, and the name `a` will be found as a member of the class X.

Comment: @BenVoigt It concerns lookup of names *appearing in* class members, regardless of whether lookup results in a class member. That's what I thought the whole point of your answer was: your answer claims that because the mem-initalizer-list appears inside a function body, lookup of the names inside the mem-initializer-list is covered by 3.4.1p8. If I'm just missing something obvious, could you please explain it in a way that I can understand?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil Thanks, I can't find anything in the standard to suggest that you're wrong so that gives some food for thought, but in a member initialisation of `a(a)`, how is it then possible for the second `a` to refer to a function parameter? Or is that second `a` not supposed to be covered by p8 (like Ben Voigt's comment suggests)?

Comment: @hvd No, the second `a` is not covered by §3.4.1/8. Note that the following text was introduced at the start of this paragraph in C++14: "For the members of a class X", which didn't exist in C++11.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil That's mainly a clarification. C++11 has "A name used in the definition of a member function (9.3) of class `X` following the function's *declarator-id*". There are some subtleties, but none that matter here. If you say that second `a` isn't covered by p8, even though it appears inside a member function's body, then which part of 3.4.1 (if any) is it supposed to be covered by? As far as I know, the lookup rules for the 3rd and 4th `a`s in `C(int a) : a(a) { b = a; }` are the same, and that 4th `a` is definitely covered by p8 (see the example). It's that 2nd `a` that's different.

Comment: @hvd `As far as I know, the lookup rules for the 3rd and 4th as in C(int a) : a(a) { b = a; } are the same, and that 4th a is definitely covered by p8 (see the example)` The rules are not the same. The 4th `a` is covered by 3.4.1/11 (C++14): `During the lookup for a name used as a default argument (8.3.6) in a function parameter-declaration-clause
or used in the expression of a mem-initializer for a constructor (12.6.2), the function parameter names are visible and hide the names of entities declared in the block, class or namespace scopes containing the function declaration.`

Comment: @BenVoigt Actually, Wake up Brazil is right: "or used in the expression of a mem-initializer for a constructor". I did miss that, thanks for pointing it out. (I'm not sure it changes anything, but it does mean I should re-read things, I clearly did miss some details.)

Comment: @BenVoigt Presumably a typo. :) I claimed that lookup was the same for the 3rd and 4th `a`. The 3rd `a` is covered by 3.4.1p11, the 4th `a` isn't.

Comment: @BenVoigt The example in 3.4.1p8 makes it clear that it covers the search for names used in a class member, regardless of whether the names resolve to a class member. The example in 3.4.1p8 mentions all scopes that are searched for `i`, including non-class scopes. In `int b; struct X { X(int a) { b = a; } };`, the class member is `X::X`, both `b` and `a` are unqualified names used in the function body of that class member, and 3.4.1p8 does specify that `b` is found in global scope (in p8.5). But Wake up Brazil raised valid points for the lookup of `a`, so I'm no longer certain about that one.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, I think 12.6.2 (and indeed 3.3.7) is sufficient to specify the meaning of the first `a` in `struct X { X() : a(1) { } int a; };`, without needing 3.4 at all. One oddity that arises from *not* involving 3.4, though, is how `class A { }; typedef A B; class C : B { C() : B() { } };` would be covered (or even put `C` is in a namespace). Implementations accept this, and this seems perfectly sensible, even though `C` has no injected class name `B`, so `B` has to be found from higher-up scopes. But you need 3.4 for higher-up scopes to be searched. So maybe 3.4 is needed after all.

Comment: @BenVoigt Then again, that's covered by the `mem-initializer-id: class-or-decltype` production and 12.6.2p3, and even though the `class-or-decltype` ends up as a single `identifier`, it's not the `mem-initializer-id: identifier` production and 12.6.2p2. Oh how confusing.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think "The scope containing the constructor's definition" is supposed to be a single scope, hence "the" scope, but I may be wrong about that.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's actually yet another issue with the wording causing a lot of confusion for me: the wording in 3.4.1 that should refer to block scope actually refers to blocks (compound statements) and links to 6.3 (describing the `{`...`}` syntax), not to 3.3.3, describing block scope. Although the scope of function parameters is described in 3.3.3, they aren't in any block.

Comment: @hvd: The function parameters are in scope for the entire function body, including here, but because of 12.6.2, the search isn't done in the current scope, but in class scope, and that definitely excludes the parameters.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, sorry for being unclear, I knew that, it's not directly related to our current discussion, it's just something that came up because it's in the same paragraphs. :) We're probably getting too far off track, and since I think we do agree on which C++ programs are valid and which aren't, since we're just not in full agreement on how the words in the standard specify that, and we're causing more confusion than we're solving, perhaps we should just give up here.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a disappointing answer, and I welcome an answer that proves me wrong, but I don't think it's there.

3.4 starts as (emphasis mine):

> **3.4 Name lookup [basic.lookup]**
>
> The name lookup rules apply uniformly to all names (including *typedef-names* (7.1.3), *namespace-names* (7.3), and *class-names* (9.1)) **wherever the grammar allows such names in the context discussed by a particular rule**. [...]

If 12.6.2 says an unqualified identifier is not looked up according to the ordinary unqualified name lookup rules in that context, if 12.6.2 says an unqualified identifier in that context gets different lookup rules, then it isn't necessary for 3.4 to explicitly exclude that context, because it's already implicitly excluded.

There is a note in 3.4.1p11 that refers back to 12.6.2, but it only covers the expressions used in a constructor initialisation list, not the members.